# What are your favorite data sets for multiple linear regression and multiple logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression

What are you favorite data sets for which you can develop multiple linear regression and multiple logistical regression models, and for exploring the art of multiple regression?

I'm imagining data sets with a moderate number of observations, predictors, and responses, and predictors and responses that are continuous quantitative, discrete quantitative, n-ary categorical, and binary categorical.

I think of datasets of book, movie, and video-game information; car, cybersecurity, and programming-language information; and plant and medical information. I could consider data sets on environmental, chemical, mechanical, or energetic processes.

Comment: One repo people like ot look at is the UCI one: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php?format=&task=reg&att=num&area=&numAtt=10to100&numIns=&type=&sort=typeUp&view=list